# How do I return all conflict documents from a Notes Database?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I want to get all conflict documents from a Notes database.  So far, i've got this:

```
Domino.NotesSession notesSession;
Domino.NotesDatabase notesDatabase = this.OpenDatabase(out notesSession);

Domino.NotesDateTime dateTime = notesSession.CreateDateTime(String.Empty);

Domino.NotesDocumentCollection results =
    notesDatabase.Search(this.SearchString, dateTime, 0);
```

It works with, for example:

```
searchString = "@Contains(ShortName;\"Bob\")";
```

How can I do the equivalent for conflict documents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
searchString = "@IsAvailable($Conflict)";
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a field on a document that flags any Notes document as a conflict called "$Conflict". If it's present on the document, then you know it's a conflict, (like Carlos is eluding to).

You can create a view in the database that has the formula.

Select @isAvailable("$Conflict")

and then loop through all documents in the view. It looks like you're doing it in Java so I think it would look like this

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.util.*;
//.....
//.....
        Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();
        Database db = s.getDatabase("server", "filename");
        View vw = db.getView("viewname");
        Document doc = null;
        doc = vw.getFirstDocument();

        while (doc != null) {
            // do what you want in here.
            doc = vw.getNextDocument(doc);
            }
```

You'll need to make sure you have added the Domino jars to your project. [This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-eclipse/) is a good reference for setting up the eclipse IDE for Domino java development.

PS. You can also modify the design of the database to minimise replication conflicts. But I won't bore you here with the details. Post a comment if you would like to know and ill provide instructions on this thread.